# Generating every possible order of operators

Tags: java

I have created a method in which every possible order of +,-,*,/ are created but I am having issues getting orders to be created for multiples of the same operator.

So far I used this which works but it generated the same order several times which I don't want:
`generateOperatorOrders(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/", "+", "-", "*", "/", "+", "-", "*", "/")), new Stack<>(), 3);`

This is my method code:

```
private void generateOperatorOrders(List<String> operators, Stack<String> permutation, int size) {
        if (permutation.size() == size) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(permutation.toArray(new String[0])));
            possibleOperatorOrders.add(permutation.toArray(new String[0]));
        }
        String[] availableOperators = operators.toArray(new String[0]);
        for (String string : availableOperators) {
            permutation.push(string);
            operators.remove(string);
            generateOperatorOrders(operators, permutation, size);
            operators.add(permutation.pop());
        }
    }
```

This is what I am using when getting just the standard possible orders of operators without ones that have the same operators.
`generateOperatorOrders(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/")), new Stack<>(), 3);`

```
[+, -, /]
[+, *, /]
[+, *, -]
[+, /, -]
[+, /, *]
[-, *, /]
[-, *, +]
[-, /, +]
[-, /, *]
[-, +, *]
[-, +, /]
[*, /, +]
[*, /, -]
[*, +, -]
[*, +, /]
[*, -, /]
[*, -, +]
[/, +, -]
[/, +, *]
[/, -, *]
[/, -, +]
[/, *, +]
[/, *, -]
```

Comment: Your input has 3 occurrences of (say) '*' so each occurrence is treated as a separate operator.  One way to fix the apparent duplication of output is to filter to remove the duplication, e.g., by storing the result in a Set.

Comment: @another-dave So instead of a Stack use a HashSet?

Comment: Or post-process the result by loading the content of the Stack into a HashSet.

Comment: Why exactly are you passing in `Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/", "+", "-", "*", "/", "+", "-", "*", "/")` - should it be `Arrays.asList("+", "-", "*", "/")`?

Comment: He wants permutations that have 3 instances of each operator, so the 'simple' way to do that is to present each operator 3 times in the input; but the cost is that each instance is treated independently: "+(1)+(2)+(3)" is not the same permutation as "+(1)+(3)+(2)",  where "+(N)" is my clumsy notation for "the Nth instance of '+' in the input string".